# Why does this program fail to copy files?

Tags: perl, copy

this morning, my friend and I discussed and wrote the below code. The idea behind this Perl script is to create the directory structure and copy the files to the corresponding directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Path;
use File::Copy;
use Path::Class;
use File::Basename qw/dirname/;
my $src = "/Vijay/new.txt";
unless (open(MYFILE, "file1")) {
    die ("cannot open input file file1\n");
}
$line = <MYFILE>;
while ($line ne "") {
    print ($line);
    mkdir_and_copy($src,$line);
    $line = <MYFILE>;
}
sub mkdir_and_copy {
    my ($from, $to) = @_;
    my($directory, $filename) = $to =~ m/(.*\/)(.*)$/;
    print("creating dir $directory");
    system "mkdir -p $directory";
    print("copying file $from to $to");
    system "cp -f $from $to";
    return;
}
```

The above piece of code creates the directory structure, but fails to copy the files to the corresponding directory. Could you please let us know, where exactly we are wrong?

Contents of file1:

```
test/test1/test2/test.txt
```

Contents of new.txt:

```
Shell/Test/test1/test1.txt
Shell/Test/test2/test2.txt
Shell/Test/test3/test3.txt
```

Output:

```
> ./mypgm.pl
test/test1/test2/test.txt
creating dir test/test1/test2/copying file /Vijay/new.txt to     test/test1/test2/test.txt
cp: cannot access /Vijay/new.txt: No such file or directory
>
```

The directory `Vijay` has the file `new.txt` with the above mentioned content.

Thanks in advance,

Vijay

---

Hello everyone,
I just modified my code. Please refer the below section of code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl        
use File::Path;    
use File::Copy;    
use File::Basename qw/dirname/;    

my $src = "./Vijay/new.txt";       
unless (open(MYFILE, "file1"))    
{    
die ("cannot open input file file1\n");    
}

$line = ;
while ($line ne "")
{
print ($line); print("\n");
mkdir_and_copy($src,$line);
$line = ""; }

sub mkdir_and_copy        
{      
my ($from, $to) = @_;    
my($directory, $filename) = $to =~ m/(.\/)(.)$/;    
$temp = $directory.$filename;    
print("Creating dirrectory $directory \n");    
if(! -d $directory)    
{    
mkpath($directory) #or die "Failed to create path";    
}    
printf("From: $from \n");    
printf("To: $temp \n");    
copy($from,$temp) or die "Failed to Copy";    
return;    
}
```

Now, it creates the exact directory structure and copies the file to the corresponding directory. Could you please tell me that, whether the above code is a proper one?

Comment: Can you add the output please?

Comment: Read a book or two about the language you are using and possibly programming in general. Seriously. There isn't a line in your script that is written correctly. I'm sorry if this comment hurts your feelings, but this is where you need improvement.

Comment: Contents of file1:        
test/test1/test2/test.txt    

Contents of new.txt:    
Shell/Test/test1/test1.txt    
Shell/Test/test2/test2.txt    
Shell/Test/test3/test3.txt    
    
Output:    
> ./mypgm.pl    
test/test1/test2/test.txt    
creating dir test/test1/test2/copying file /Vijay/new.txt to     test/test1/test2/test.txt    
cp: cannot access /Vijay/new.txt: No such file or directory    
>    

The Directory 'Vijay' has the file new.txt with the above mentioned content.

Comment: @msv: It hurts. However, for a beginner and someone who wasted all the opportunities given, deserves this :(
Thank you.

Comment: @gbcon: cp -r, cp-rf both gives me the same result :(

Comment: cp: cannot access /Vijay/new.txt: No such file or directory . It's trying to copy a file located in a folder called Vijay from the root directory / . Is it really the case? Or you mean "./Vijay/new.txt" ( from the current directory)

Comment: When I started refactoring this program I noticed that it is hopeless confused the way it is written. I cannot figure out whether you want to operate on the content of `/Vijay/new.txt` or copy the file itself - as it is now, the program achieves neither. Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3475956/edit) and add, in simple words, a low-level description of the algorithm you want to implement.

Comment: @daxim: Hi, my ultimate aim is to read a file which has a directory structure, create the same directory structure along with the files.
Eg: file1: Test/Test1/text1    
The script has to read the above line from file1
Then, it has to create the same directory structure and copy the files from the source directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is not clear to me, but perhaps this will help you solve the problem:

```
# Perl scripts should always include this.
# Your original script was generating some useful warnings.
use strict;
use warnings;

my $src = "/Vijay/new.txt";
my $f1  = 'file1';

# This is the recommended way to open a file --
# that is, using a lexical file handle.
open(my $file_handle, '<', $f1) or die "open() failed : $f1 : $!";

# This is the typical way of iterating over the lines in a file.
while (my $line = <$file_handle>){
    # You probably want to remove the newline
    # before passing the line to mkdir_and_copy()
    chomp $line;

    mkdir_and_copy($src, $line);
}

sub mkdir_and_copy {
    my ($from, $to) = @_;
    my ($directory, $filename) = $to =~ m/(.*\/)(.*)$/;

    # When writing a script that makes system() calls,
    # start by simply printing them. After everything
    # looks good, convert the print commands to system() calls.
    print "system(): mkdir -p $directory", "\n";
    print "system(): cp -f $from $to",     "\n";

    # The return is not needed.
}
```

When I run the script with the inputs you provided, here's the output:

```
system(): mkdir -p test/test1/test2/
system(): cp -f /Vijay/new.txt test/test1/test2/test.txt
```

This can't be your intent. In particular, why are you iterating over `file1` when it contains only one line? Perhaps you meant to iterate over `new.txt`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, FM. Actually, I should iterate new.txt.
Because it has the directory structure that needs to be created. I'm totally confused now. Could you please make it a bit more clear to me?
My questions are, the new.txt file has the directory structure that needs to be created. Then, why am I iterating file1?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do if something "does't work" is to catch errors and to look at them. Then to investigate content of variables. In your case the variable `$to` just contains the file name, so the script copies it into the current working directory, I'd imagine, not into the newly created directory.

**HOWEVER**, the methods you're using to get your job done are not exactly the best. It would be better to actually use `File::Path` and `File::Copy`, and in particular your way of splitting a path into directory and filename at the first slash is anything but general. This sort of thing should be done in libraries, of which Perl has many.

Comment: Fine. What exactly I should do to make the script to copy the files to the corresponding directories? Could you please be specific? I tried with Shell Scripting, and it does work. I do not understand, why the same kinda login doesn't work with Perl!

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet your `$line` variable still has a newline appended to it. The input returned from the filehandle input operator (`<MYFILE>`) includes the record separator (usually the newline character(s) for your OS). Try this:

```
$line = <MYFILE>;
chomp($line);
```