# use list of files to to copy and move to new directory in perl

Tags: perl, batch-file, copy

I have a list of file names in a txt file. They correlate to pdfs I have. I would like to copy the actual pdf files that are listed in that list, to a directory. The files that need to be copied are contained in different subdirectories as well. What is the easiest way to do this using perl?
Thanks!

Comment: The question is as yet unanswerable - you have not yet specified whether the names in the text file are the names of the PDF files ('correlate' suggests that the names in the text file are *not* the names of the PDF files).  Also, how is the directory specified?  And what has to be done about pathnames on the PDF files?  Does the directory structure have to be copied, or are the files copied from the pathnames in the text file to a flat structure in the target directory?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475956/why-does-this-program-fail-to-copy-files

Comment: The names in the list are the same as the actual files. All the files exist within one top-most directory. The directory structure does not need to be copied, only the actual file. The text file only list file names for example:
1234.pdf
1235.pdf
1236.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend that you read perlfaq5: [How do I copy a file](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-copy-a-file%3f)?

After that, it shouldn't be too hard; Untested code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;
use File::Copy;
use File::Spec;

open my $files_fh, '<', '/path/to/txt';

my $files_dir       = shift // '/path/to/dir';
my $destination_dir = shift // '/path/to/dir';

while (<$files_fh>) {
    chomp;
    next unless -d (my $file = File::Spec->catfile($files_dir, $_) );

    copy($file, $file . '.cpy');
    move($file . '.cpy', $destination_dir);
    say "Copied [$file] and moved it to [$destination_dir]";
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to copy a list of files without using a loop?  Like does `copy` not support taking an array as an argument?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you use the perl File::Copy package.

```
use File::Copy;
$filetobecopied = "myhtml.html.";
$newfile = "html/myhtml.html.";
copy($filetobecopied, $newfile) or die "File cannot be copied.";
```